# Getting error SqlException was unhandled by user code

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I'm creating a Registration form for new user sign up. Im getting the following error. I searched for solution on google, but none of them helped me.

> Error : A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server).

Could you please help me out with this?

Code :

```
public partial class Registration : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from regform where username='" + TextBox1.Text + "'", con);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (dr.Read())
        {
            Label1.Text = "User Name is Already Exist";
        }
        else
        {
            Label1.Text = "UserName is Available";
        }
        con.Close();
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;");
        con.Open();
        String str = "Insert into regform values ( '" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + TextBox2.Text + "','" + TextBox4.Text + "','" + TextBox5.Text + "')";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        Session["name"] = TextBox1.Text;
        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: for starters get rid of ` String str = "Insert into regform values ( '" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + TextBox2.Text + "','" + TextBox4.Text + "','" + TextBox5.Text + "')";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);` this is potential SQL Injection and refactor your code to use Parameterized Query's

Comment: First you need to enable remote access to your SQL Server see [7 things to check to resolve  “A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server…”](http://www.sswug.org/articlesection/default.aspx?TargetID=44331). Second, **Use Parameters** with your query, third. You can get a count of user instead of selecting the records for user.

Comment: aside from the obvious vulernability to sql injection, the error is self explanatory.

Answer (score 1):

Your connection string seems off

```
Data Source=.\;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;
```

Using the `AttachDbFilename=...` element indicates you're using SQL Server **Express**, but the Express default installation would be using the `SQLEXPRESS` instance name - so your connection string should be

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;
```

Have you tried with this connection string? Any luck?

If that doesn't work - can you make sure what *edition* of SQL Server you have installed? Connecting to it in Management Studio - what do you use as server name?? And if you're connected - what does `SELECT @@Version` return?

Answer (score 0):

utilize this example taken from [Retrieving Data Using a DataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
you will see quickly where you are making the slight code mistake

```
static void HasRows(SqlConnection connection)
{
    using (connection)
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
          "SELECT CategoryID, CategoryName FROM Categories;",
          connection);
        connection.Open();

        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", reader.GetInt32(0),
                    reader.GetString(1));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No rows found.");
        }
        reader.Close();
    }
}
```

change your code here

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from regform where username='" + TextBox1.Text + "'", con);
```

Either create a Property or even better a Stored Procedure

Comment: using `string.Format` to format queries is still prone to SQL injection. Also the field is of numeric type, and expects single quotes around the passed value.

Comment: `Habib` I agree but I am giving him an example I think that using properties in this case would be the more optimal path to take also he needs to change his Insert to utilize parameters and or create a Stored Procedure in my opinion I removed the string.Format as well..

Comment: taken my downvote back, an example with `SqlParameter` would be great for OP, IMO

Answer (score 0):

The exception suggests that your connection string is wrong.

Isn't `Initial Catalog=InstanceDB` missing from your connection string? Where `InstanceDB` is the name of your database.

---

Use command parameters! If you don't, you will face several issues:

- You will be threatened by SQL injection attacks!
- You will have to deal with the special handling of null entries.
- You will have to escape quotes in strings.
- You will have to use the right formatting for date values.
- Lengthy string concatenations look ugly.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
    "SELECT * FROM regform WHERE username = @usr", con);
cmd.AddWithValue("@usr", TextBox1.Text);
```

Do the same for the insert statement.